# jZip possible malicious software.

Tags: discussion

[jZip](https://superuser.com/search?q=jzip) was mentioned a few times on SU, the problem is that it is [possible malicious software](http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/jzip.com).

The most prominent problems I've found are:

- The website was registered via a proxy service, there's no way to figure out who owns it
- The website seems to be associated with the [Panthera Project](http://www.mywot.com/en/forum/3727-pantheraproject-net), which is a project of the Discordia Limited company, part of the RIAA 'P2P hunters'.
- A scan on virustotal.com of the Setup didn't reveal anything, but I'm not eager to test it out by installing it

Yes, I know that this is very vague information...so, shall I further investigate this or leave it be?

Comment: you should really try chat more often :P

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: True, I always forget about that one. :)

Comment: Just press the link in the sidebar -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Anything we can do to make the internet a safer please for those who can't fight for themselves!**

I preemptively killed all current instances, as most where just mentions in regular zip questions.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the last reference on a question

https://superuser.com/search?q=jzip

Let me know if this needs to be added to the blacklist in some way; that's a developer only function because it is so dangerous.